# Get value from child of a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firebase

I have the following structure:

```
{
"user": {
    "time": 10,
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to retrieve and output content from the child of a child.
So in this case, I need to retrieve the value of "time" of the "user".

I have the following code:

```
var pageRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/");

    pageRef.child("user").on("value", function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        $('#user_value').html(snapshot.val());
    });
```

This currently only gets the value of "user" which outputs `Object {time: 10}` in the console.

Hope I've been clear. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what your are trying to do but try this : 

snapshot.val().time

Comment: Or this : 
pageRef.child("user.time").on ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try assigning the value from the snapshot to a local variable. From there you can use whichever properties you need.

```
var pageRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/");

pageRef.child("user").on("value", function (snapshot) {
  var obj = snapshot.val(); // this sets: obj = { "time": 10 }
  $('#user_value').html(obj.time);
});
```

If you only need the time value, you can change the URL to grab the single property only.

```
var userRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/user/time");

userRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
  var time = snapshot.val();
  $('#user_value').html(time);
});
```